# Can we split the (will + linking verb) in a passive form and put an adverb between them?

Tags: modal-verbs, linking-verbs

I was writing this on my Facebook post:

> ... it will certainly be accepted

A friend of mine corrected me it should have been written like this:

> ... it certainly will be accepted

However, I don't see the reason why I had written that incorrectly. I would like to confirm it here. Why is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it will certainly be accepted

Your example is fine.

A guide on placing adverbs mid-position in a sentence is shown below.

> Where there is more than one verb, mid position means after the first auxiliary verb or after a modal verb:

> The government has occasionally been forced to change its mind. (after the first auxiliary verb)

> You can definitely never predict what will happen. (after a modal verb)

> We mightn’t ever have met. (after the modal verb and before the auxiliary verb)

[reference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position)

Answer (score 2):

As a native British English speaker I would accept either equally. The second version can be interpreted as putting emphasis on "will". Consider the sentence

> "Despite the arguments against, it certainly **will** be accepted."

but other than that they are interchangeable.